# Como preencher todas as celulas em branco com o valor de cima Excel VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Preciso criar uma macro que ao rodar, ela preencha todas as células vazias com o que estão acima delas: Segue print como exemplo

[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtcFA.png)

```html
'Macro que tenho até o momento, porém não está dando certo, alguém pode me ajudar?

Sub FillCellsFromAbove()
    ' Turn off screen updating to improve performance
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error Resume Next
    ' Look in column A
    With Columns(1)
        ' For blank cells, set them to equal the cell above
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Formula = "=R[-1]C"
        'Convert the formula to a value
        .Value = .Value
    End With
    Err.Clear
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

r.com/IXYFP.png

Answer (score 0):

Altere o código disponibilizado para:

```
Sub FillCellsFromAbove()
    ' Turn off screen updating to improve performance
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error Resume Next
    ' Look in column A
    With Selection
        ' For blank cells, set them to equal the cell above
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Formula = "=R[-1]C"
        'Convert the formula to a value
        .Value = .Value
    End With
    Err.Clear
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

perceba que substituí "Columns(1)" por "Selection". Isto, porque Columns(1) trabalha com TODAS as células da coluna A, o que não parece ter sentido. Ao utilizar Selection, a única coisa que você deverá fazer é selecionar as células da Coluna A que deverão receber os valores ao rodar a macro. Para tanto é imperativo que, pelo menos, a primeira célula dessa seleção não esteja em branco. Uma vez feita a seleção, rode a macro. Pronto.